# Is it possible to use lists in order to forecast data in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, forecasting

At the moment I have been using lists to plot data and wish to find out a pattern for forecasting. Trying to use data frames have not helped me and have caused great discomfort. Is it possible to use python lists and machine learning or pattern recognition algorithm to forecast data? I am new to python :)

Comment: It depends. Do the machine algorithms you are using accept lists as input parameters?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a program which could take inputs of timestamps and use it to predict future timestamps. After a long time what has worked for me is using timestamps with only hours:minutes:seconds format and converting them to float numbers. Then using those float numbers and paired it with the entry number of the timestamp. So I had a 2D list just to gather the data neatly into one pile.

Example : timestamp_1, 0
          timestamp_2, 1
          timestamp_3, 2

Then assigned two variables which will take the data of one column. The float numbers would be on the y-axis and x axis would be the sequence of numbers, eg. 0,1,2,3,... and so forth.

Then using svr_lin.fit which is linear regression I was able to plot a graph that matches all points since it will be a line due to the numbers in x-axis. Finally, with svr_lin.predict and a loop I can print future data points. Hope this can help people who are trying to get "future" timestamps using python.

Code:

```
data = [[timestamp_1, 0],
        [timestamp_2, 1],
        [timestamp_3, 2],
        [timestamp_4, 3],
        #continues...
         ]]

list_time = []
list_numbers = []

list_time = [i[0] for i in data]
list_numbers = [i[1] for i in data]

list_numbers = np.reshape(list_number, (len(list_numbers), 1))

svr_lin = SVR(kernel='linear', C=1e3)

svr_lin.fit(list_numbers, list_time)

plt.scatter(list_numbers, list_time)
plt.plot(list_numbers, svr_lin.predict(list_numbers)) #in a different colour
plt.show

'''x is out of sample and starting point I have kept in sample however, starting 
point does not need to be the 0th element.'''

for i in range(0,x):
    print(svr_lin.predict(i))
```

Siraj Raval and stack overflow users' code has helped me a lot.